# Is it possible to download a file from server whithout giving the file URL?

Tags: android, file, security, url, download

I was wondering if it was possible to download a file without giving the specific file URL.
For instance, making an **http request** and inside the response were the file or the content of the file.
I'm able to download a file already giving the exact URL.
For instance, [txt file](https://androidnetworktester.googlecode.com/files/10kb.txt).
But, what I want next is to **protect** that URL and make it **private**.
If there is another way, then please explain me

Comment: If you're **downloading a file**, no matter what, it's on the user's machine. They have the freedom to do whatever they want with it. Whenever you're transferring to a user, you're giving the file away. It's just how the Internet works.

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear. You will have to publish some URL to allow others to access the server, but that URL doesn't necessarily have to lead to an individual file - for example it could point to a RESTful webservice that then maps args to actual URLs and returns those files. The original URLs wouldn't be disclosed, but what exactly is the point?

Comment: In short: **NO**. You can **mask** the URL (by using some kind of URL shorteners), but you have to point the link to the URL anyway.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explained very well, here is what I want:
1.-To download a file on a server
2.-That the file is some kind of protected
3.- Somhow hide the url of the file on the app 
maybe thats a little bit less confussing

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to facilitate server-client communication without using http request, referred to as [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/). To achieve the goal you asked - **"Download a file from server without giving the file URL"**, you can do as follow:

1. Download Thrift, Build and Install Apache Thrift compiler

   You can follow steps on [official website](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource).
2. Writing a .thrift file (For my example, I named it as "test.thrift")

   For your example, you can define as below:

   ```
   service MyServer {

       binary getFileFromServer()

   }
   ```
3. Then, open you terminal and run

   ```
   thrift --gen java test.thrift
   ```

   I'll get a "MyServer.java" file and both server/client sides should include this file for implementing. Assuming your server side is prepared for providing file data as binary. In your Android app, you just need to specify the socket, protocol, transport, host, and port for connecting server. And if you would like to get file from server, just using your Client object to call "getFileFromServer()", then you can get the byte[] of your file. For instance:

   ```
   public TSocket socket = new TSocket(your_host, your_port);
   public TFramedTransport transport = new TFramedTransport(socket);
   public TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
   public Client myClient = new Client(protocol);
   ```

   call a thread to get file from server:

   ```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run(){

           // this block should be wrapped with try/catch

           transport.open();
           byte[] myFileInByteArray = myClient.getFileFromServer();
           // your custom function for decoding
           decodeByteArrayIntoFile(myFileInByteArray);
           transport.close(); 
       }
   }).start();
   ```

The above is the only way I can think of to download a file from server without giving the file URL, but your still need to connect to your server first. Hope this can help.

Comment: I will try this and let you know, just I've never hear of it before so something new to learn thanks